# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_sqlalchemy' after deploying to Azure #Python#FLASK#SQLite

Tags: python-3.x, azure, sqlite, flask

### I built a simple todo app using Python, SQLite, and FLASK. Here is a list of packages downloaded inside my virtual environment.

```
click==7.1.2
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.4
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.2
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
SQLAlchemy==1.3.19
Werkzeug==1.0.1
```

---

**The apps works as intended on local server, when I deployed it to Azure App Service, the website url ran into an error, here are chunks of error messages displayed on azure "Dignose and solve problems" tool:**

```
2020-09-04T01:01:56.214383481Z   File "/home/site/wwwroot/app.py", line 2, in 
2020-09-04T01:01:56.214399081Z     from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
2020-09-04T01:01:56.214461881Z ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_sqlalchemy'
2020-09-04T01:01:56.214481081Z [2020-09-04 01:01:56 +0000] [45] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 45)
2020-09-04T01:01:56.352306124Z [2020-09-04 01:01:56 +0000] [42] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2020-09-04T01:01:56.352713924Z [2020-09-04 01:01:56 +0000] [42] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.

2020-09-04T01:01:53.584987085Z Generating `gunicorn` command for 'app:app'
2020-09-04T01:01:53.957940395Z Writing output script to '/opt/startup/startup.sh'
2020-09-04T01:01:54.279983390Z Found virtual environment .tar.gz archive.
2020-09-04T01:01:54.280612491Z Removing existing virtual environment directory /antenv3.6...
2020-09-04T01:01:54.283122391Z Extracting to directory /antenv3.6...
2020-09-04T01:01:54.833191954Z Using packages from virtual environment antenv3.6 located at /antenv3.6.
2020-09-04T01:01:54.833722854Z Updated PYTHONPATH to ':/antenv3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages'
2020-09-04T01:01:55.632256500Z [2020-09-04 01:01:55 +0000] [42] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
2020-09-04T01:01:55.633461900Z [2020-09-04 01:01:55 +0000] [42] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (42)
2020-09-04T01:01:55.634047501Z [2020-09-04 01:01:55 +0000] [42] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2020-09-04T01:01:55.644017104Z [2020-09-04 01:01:55 +0000] [45] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 45
2020-09-04T01:01:56.177488970Z [2020-09-04 01:01:56 +0000] [45] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
```

**I clearly have flask_sqlalchemy modules installed inside my virtual environment, why is it giving me this error?
Is it even possible to deploy SQLite webapps? or does it have to some online database servers?**

Thanks.

Comment: When you deploy to Azure it creates a new virtual environment. It needs a `requirements.txt` file to know what to install. Do you have an up-to-date `requirements.txt`?

Comment: @PGHE  Thanks for the reply, it was helpful. I had to make a requirements.txt file using **pip3 freeze --user > requirements.txt**

Answer (score 1):

pip freeze > requirements.txt

solved the problem. Thanks